# Make the Message "Article successfully saved" Fade Away after x seconds

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator

Let's say that I edit and save an article. The message "Article successfully saved"appears in the `system-message-container div` and sticks there. Let's say that now I am doing some editing and I am interrupted by something else and I come back after a while on my article. I see the message "Article successfully saved" and click on close. After that I realized that in fact the message was there since the first save and that I didn't save the second edit.

I know that I could pay more attention (not only on web-editing by the way) but is there a way to make the message "Article successfully saved" fade away after 20 secondes.

PS: *You will tell me that I can click on save and close if I am not sure but I have found my self in situation when I have mess up the article when I come back and because I saw this message I told myself "ok not problem, just close the article and open it again without saving and you will get back the version you had when you came back but...".

Edit : content of `administrator\templates\isis\html\layouts\joomla\system\message.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Administrator
 * @subpackage  Template.Isis
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$msgList = $displayData['msgList'];

$alert = array('error' => 'alert-error', 'warning' => '', 'notice' => 'alert-info', 'message' => 'alert-success');
?>
<div id="system-message-container">
    <?php if (is_array($msgList) && $msgList) : ?>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <?php foreach ($msgList as $type => $msgs) : ?>
            <div class="alert <?php echo $alert[$type]; ?>">
                <h4 class="alert-heading"><?php echo JText::_($type); ?></h4>
                <?php if ($msgs) : ?>
                    <?php foreach ($msgs as $msg) : ?>
                        <p><?php echo $msg; ?></p>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

content of `administrator\templates\isis\js\template.js`:

```
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Administrator
 * @subpackage  Templates.isis
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 * @since       3.0
 */

(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('*[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();

        // Turn radios into btn-group
        $('.radio.btn-group label').addClass('btn');
        $('.btn-group label:not(.active)').click(function()
        {
            var label = $(this);
            var input = $('#' + label.attr('for'));

            if (!input.prop('checked')) {
                label.closest('.btn-group').find('label').removeClass('active btn-success btn-danger btn-primary');
                if (input.val() == '') {
                    label.addClass('active btn-primary');
                } else if (input.val() == 0) {
                    label.addClass('active btn-danger');
                } else {
                    label.addClass('active btn-success');
                }
                input.prop('checked', true);
            }
        });
        $('.btn-group input[checked=checked]').each(function()
        {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $('label[for=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').addClass('active btn-primary');
            } else if ($(this).val() == 0) {
                $('label[for=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').addClass('active btn-danger');
            } else {
                $('label[for=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').addClass('active btn-success');
            }
        });
        // add color classes to chosen field based on value
        $('select[class^="chzn-color"], select[class*=" chzn-color"]').on('liszt:ready', function(){
            var select = $(this);
            var cls = this.className.replace(/^.(chzn-color[a-z0-9-_]*)$.*/, '\1');
            var container = select.next('.chzn-container').find('.chzn-single');
            container.addClass(cls).attr('rel', 'value_' + select.val());
            select.on('change click', function()
            {
                container.attr('rel', 'value_' + select.val());
            });

        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps you could include a timestamp with the save message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following jQuery for this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#system-message-container').fadeOut('fast');
}, 5000);
```

`5000` is 5 seconds, therefore you can change this value to whatever you want

**Where do I add this code?**

<strike>**Option 1:** This is a long and winded method. You can create a small plugin that calls this jQuery code.</strike>

**Option 2:** Simply add the above code to the following file:

```
administrator/templates/isis/js/template.js
```

Please note that Option 2 is considered a core hack, therefore if you install a Joomla update and there have been some changes to the admin template, then this change will be overridden.

## Update >> Option 3:

Just noticed that you can also add this to the template override for system messages. So, open the following file in a text editor:

```
administrator/templates/isis/html/message.php
```

You should see on line 14, `$buffer = null;`. Directly below this, add the following:

```
$buffer .= "<script>
                setTimeout(function() {
                    jQuery('#system-message-container').fadeOut('fast');
                }, 5000);
            </script>";
```

For **success** messages only, use this:

```
$buffer .= "<script>    
                setTimeout(function() {
                    jQuery('.alert-success').parents('#system-message-container').fadeOut('fast');
                }, 5000);
            </script>";
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help! I couldn't find the file message.php in administrator/templates/isis/html but I cdid find it in: administrator\templates\isis\html\layouts\joomla\system\. I also couldn't manage to find where I am supposed to add the line in administrator/templates/isis/js/template.js, if I go with option 2

Comment: I will update the question soon :) Out at lunch

Comment: Enjoy your meal! ;-)!

Comment: Right, back. Hmm you're right, the file isn't there with new Joomla installs. maybe because I upgraded from 3.2 that I have the file. I have created it for you so you can download it and add it to that folder [here](http://pastebin.com/jX88B38J). If you would prefer to edit the template.js, you can add the code anywhere inside document ready. Perhaps after `$('*[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();` on line 13

Comment: Your the King! Thanks so much! You should be right because, I've upgraded from J2.5 to J3.3.1 directly. That's really great!

Comment: Just one last question : the time fade out is effective on all kind of messages in back end (not front end)(even errors like the one during installs or save), Is there a way to make only the div "alert alert-success" fade away?

Comment: Currently writing up a small function for you. Will update in a few mins

Comment: @Arone - updated my answer. See the last section

Comment: It's working! That's great! Thanks a lot @Lodder !

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: In which file am I supposed to add this to fade out the succes message on front end also? I have tried to look for /templates/protostar/html/message.php but it'snot there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works fine but only once. If there is a second message rendered the script is not triggered.

If you use this it works **everytime** to fade a success alert:

```
setInterval(function() {
    jQuery('.alert-success').parents('#system-message-container').fadeOut('fast');
}, 5000);
```

I use it in the front-end by adding this:

```
$buffer .= "<script>    
            setInterval(function() {
              jQuery('.alert-success').parents('#system-message-container').fadeOut('fast');
            }, 5000);
            console.log('timout triggered');
            </script>";
```

after line 14 in messages.php (originally found in templates/beez3/html/layouts/joomla/system) and put that in your template/html folder.

Comment: Just to complete this information here. I found out that using it like this doesn't work for messages generated by JS function Joomla.RenderMessages since these don't use this php file to render but they render straight from the core.js file. To support both ways of alerts you should add the interval function in your template so it's loaded on every page. Make sure to put it inside a "on document ready" statement.